# Laravel 4 - Pivot Tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I understand how relationships in Laravel (Eloquent) work, but let's say I've got a many to many relationship between two models, call them Posts and Tags.

So our relationship is fine, from Posts I can access all the related Tags, and from Tags I can get all related Posts.

But...  I have the ID of a row in the pivot table, and want to return both the Post and Tag relating to this row, how would I go about doing this?

EDIT:

Let's introduce a third Model, called Foo. This contains the ID of the row in the pivot table,
is there anyway I can create a relationship from this to the two other models?

Comment: Can you not query the join table?

Comment: Editting to try and explain abit more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Model for your pivot:

```
<?php

class PostTagPivot
{
    public function Post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }

    public function Tag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Tag');
    }
}
```

And retrieve Post and Tag via:

`$Post = PostTagPivot::find($fooBarId)->Post;`

`$Tag = PostTagPivot::find($fooBarId)->Tag;`

Comment: Make's sense now someone has told me to do it! Ha! Thanks.